# WebDAV library that supports Kerberos?

Tags: webdav, kerberos

I want to programmatically read the files of a [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29)-protected [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server.

I [tried](http://code.google.com/p/sardine/issues/detail?id=126) adding Kerberos support to [Sardine](http://code.google.com/p/sardine/) (Java), but it does not seem to work well.

Is there a WebDAV library that supports Kerberos? (any language, preferably open source)

Comment: Did you ever end up solving the issue?

Comment: @PeterVanleeuwen: No, unfortunately. But Sardine might have added the feature meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found to work is using the Sardine method classes that extend HttpRequestBase with Apache HttpClient. You will need to use both the httpclient and httpclient-win

```
try {
    CloseableHttpClient client = WinHttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpMove move = new HttpMove(fullSource, fullDestination, false);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(move);          
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201){
        System.out.println("Yay");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

throw new Exception("Unable to move node");
```

Here are the dependencies used (gradle form)

- compile group: 'com.github.lookfirst', name: 'sardine', version:
  '5.+'
- compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient',
  version: '4.5.+'
- compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-win',
  version: '4.5.+'

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If I had more time I would probably add this to the Sardine project on github. I know you tried before!

Answer (score 0):

The transport library need Kerberos support not your WebDAV lib. Try to fix that transport lib. Oracle's URLConnection does that.

Comment: The typical WebDAV library *requires* username/password, which obviously won't work in Kerberos environments. By the way, "Fixing the transport lib" is totally out-of-scope.

Comment: What is a typical WebDAV lib? Haven't of such. So, if you cannot fix it. Forget it. You maybe can change the lib.